# Caching is not working in Android Paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I have implemented application using codelabs tutorial for new Paging 3 library, which was release week ago.
The problem is application is not working in offline mode. It does not retrieve data from Room database.

Tutorial Repo link :- https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging

Code:-

1. RepoDao.kt

   ```
   @Dao
   interface RepoDao {

      @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
      suspend fun insertAll(repos: List<Repo>)

      @Query("SELECT * FROM repos WHERE " +
       "name LIKE :queryString OR description LIKE :queryString " +
       "ORDER BY stars DESC, name ASC")
      fun reposByName(queryString: String): PagingSource<Int, Repo>

      @Query("DELETE FROM repos")
      suspend fun clearRepos()
   }
   ```
2. GithubRepository.kt

   ```
   class GithubRepository(
       private val service: GithubService,
       private val database: RepoDatabase
   ) {
      fun getSearchResultStream(query: String): Flow<PagingData<Repo>> {

         val dbQuery = "%${query.replace(' ', '%')}%"
         val pagingSourceFactory = { database.reposDao().reposByName(dbQuery) }

         return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE),
            remoteMediator = GithubRemoteMediator(
                   query,
                   service,
                   database
           ),
           pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
         ).flow
      }

      companion object {
          private const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 50
      }
   }
   ```
3. SearchRepositoriesViewModel.kt

   ```
   @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
   class SearchRepositoriesViewModel(private val repository: GithubRepository) : ViewModel() {
       private var currentQueryValue: String? = null

       private var currentSearchResult: Flow<PagingData<Repo>>? = null

       fun searchRepo(queryString: String): Flow<PagingData<Repo>> {
           val lastResult = currentSearchResult
           if (queryString == currentQueryValue && lastResult != null) {
               return lastResult
           } 
           currentQueryValue = queryString
           val newResult: Flow<PagingData<Repo>> = repository.getSearchResultStream(queryString).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
           currentSearchResult = newResult
           return newResult
       }

   }
   ```
4. SearchRepositoriesActivity.kt

   ```
   @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
   class SearchRepositoriesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

       .....
       private lateinit var viewModel: SearchRepositoriesViewModel
       private val adapter = ReposAdapter()

       private var searchJob: Job? = null

       // this is where adapter get flow data from viewModel
       // initially this is called with **Android** as a query
       private fun search(query: String) {
           searchJob?.cancel()
           searchJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
               viewModel.searchRepo(query).collectLatest {
                   adapter.submitData(it)
               }
           }
       }
       .....
    }
   ```

Output:- It is just showing the empty recyclerview when application is open in offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to share your code or how you reached that conclusion I could probably help pinpoint the problem a bit better, but the codelab does load data from Room on the branch: step13-19_network_and_database

There are two components here:

`PagingSource`: Provided by Room by declaring a `@Query` with a `PagingSource` return type, will create a `PagingSource` that loads from Room. This function is called in the `pagingSourceFactory` lambda in `Pager` which expects a new instance each call.

`RemoteMediator`: `load()` called on boundary conditions where the local cache is out of data, this will fetch from network and store in the Room db, which automatically propagates updates to `PagingSource` implementation generated by Room.

One other issue you might be seeing could be related to `loadStateListener/Flow`, essentially the codelab shows an error state by checking for `CombinedLoadStates.refresh`, but this always defers to the `RemoteMediator`'s load state when available and if you want to show the locally cached data, even when `RemoteMediator` errors out, you'll need to disable hiding of the list in that case.

Note that you can access individual `LoadState` with `CombinedLoadStates.source` or `CombinedLoadStates.mediator`.

Hopefully this is enough to help you, but it's hard to guess your issue without some more concrete example / information about what you're seeing.

Edit: While the above are still good things to check for, it looks like there's an underlying issue with the library that I'm chasing down here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1341068

Edit2: This is fixed now and will be released with alpha02.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got the point of loadStateListener/Flow. I have check `loadState.source.refresh` in logs it returns the `NotLoading` when app open in offline mode. So for the simplicity i have removed the loadStateListener now. I have also added code above. It is just showing empty recyclerview. Does not show data available in database.

Comment: One thing i have also notice that in `Pager` if i **remove** the `RemoteMediator` and only use `pagingSourceFactory` it returns the data from database. So I think there is a issue with Pager.

Comment: Thanks, I've successfully repro'd this on my end and have a wip fix here in case you wanted to follow progress: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1341068

Comment: I have the same problem. The app does not show the data in the local database when you are in offline mode and search for a Repo you already search for. But instead, it just shows the Retry Button although there are data in the local database. I have opened a Github Issue Thread for this: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/issues/169